# io.Writer in Go - beginner trying to understand them

Tags: go, writer

As a beginner in Go, I have problems understanding `io.Writer`.

My target:  take a struct and write it into a json file.

Approach:
- use `encoding/json.Marshal` to convert my struct into bytes
- feed those bytes to an `os.File` Writer

This is how I got it working:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age uint
    Occupation []string
}

func MakeBytes(p Person) []byte {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(p)
    return b
}

func main() {
    gandalf := Person{
        "Gandalf",
        56,
        []string{"sourcerer", "foo fighter"},
    }

    myFile, err := os.Create("output1.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    myBytes := MakeBytes(gandalf)
    myFile.Write(myBytes)
}
```

After reading [this article](https://medium.com/@as27/a-simple-beginners-tutorial-to-io-writer-in-golang-2a13bfefea02), I changed my program to this:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age uint
    Occupation []string
}

// Correct name for this function would be simply Write
// but I use WriteToFile for my understanding
func (p *Person) WriteToFile(w io.Writer) {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(*p)
    w.Write(b)
}

func main() {
    gandalf := Person{
        "Gandalf",
        56,
        []string{"sourcerer", "foo fighter"},
    }

    myFile, err := os.Create("output2.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    gandalf.WriteToFile(myFile)
}
```

In my opinion, the first example is a more straightforward and easier to understand for a beginner... but I have the feeling that the 2nd example is the Go idiomatic way of achieving the target.

Questions:
1. is above assumption correct (that 2nd option is Go idiomatic) ?
2. Is there a difference in the above options ? Which option is better ?
3. other ways to achieve the same target ?

Thank you,

WM

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The benefit of using the second method is that if you are passing a `Writer` interface, you can pass *anything* which implements `Write` -- that is not only a file but a `http.ResponseWriter`, for example, or stdout `os.Stdout`, without changing the struct methods.

You can see this handy blog post on the package [io walkthrough](https://medium.com/go-walkthrough/go-walkthrough-io-package-8ac5e95a9fbd). The author makes the case that passing as parameter readers and writers makes your code more flexible, in part because so many functions use the `Reader` and `Writer` interface.

As you come to use Go more, you'll notice how much the standard library leans on `Reader` and `Writer` interfaces, and probably come to appreciate it :)

So this function (renamed):

```
// writes json representation of Person to Writer
func (p *Person) WriteJson(w io.Writer) error {
    b, err := json.Marshal(*p)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = w.Write(b)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return err
}
```

Would write to a **File**, http **Response**, a user's **Stdout**, or even a simple **byte Buffer**; making testing a bit simpler.

I renamed it because of what is does; that is, this function takes a `Person` struct and:

1. Marshals the struct into a **json** representation
2. Writes the json to a **`Writer`**
3. Returns any errors arising from marshalling/writing

---

One more thing, you might be confused as to what a **Writer** is, because it is **not a data type**, but rather an **interface** -- that is a behavior of a data type, a predefined method that a type implements. Anything that implements the `Write()` method, then, is considered a writer.

This can be a bit difficult for beginners to grasp at first, but there are lots of resources online to help understand interfaces (and `ReadWriters` are some of the more common interfaces to encounter, along with `Error()` (ei. all errors)).